# Joomla 2.5 registration custom field as dropdown?

Tags: joomla

I added some extra field to Joomla 2.5. Everything working great. For example, I added "country" to registration.xml (components/com_users/models/forms):

```
<field name="country" type="text"
        description="COM_USERS_REGISTER_COUNTRY_DESC"
        filter="string"
        label="COM_USERS_REGISTRATION_COUNTRY"
        required="true"
        size="40"
    />
```

But how to add a dropdown list? I want to give my users ability to select country from the list.

And similar question: I also added birthday field. How to add jQuery datepicker here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion you should not edit Joomla core files. This could break your installation in future updates.

Although I don't recommend it, take a look at [Standard form field and parameter types @ Joomla Docs](http://docs.joomla.org/Standard_form_field_and_parameter_types). At that page, see *list* for your dropdown list and *calendar* for your date.

Another way of adding extra fields would be with a extension. Check out:

- [ExtendedReg (commercial)](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/authentication/14303)
- [Community Builder](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/clients-a-communities/communities/210)

Answer (score 3):

Joomla 2.5 has a 'profile' plugin to handle extra registration fields. You can edit that or write your own plugin. This avoids editing core files. Example of a country list using a database call (your database must have the table of counties). My table has country codes in two and three letters and I want to save the 3 letter code (example CAD).

```
<field
            name="country"
            type="sql"
            id="country"
            description="PLG_USER_PROFILE_FIELD_COUNTRY_DESC"
            filter="string"
            label="PLG_USER_PROFILE_FIELD_COUNTRY_LABEL"
            message="PLG_USER_PROFILE_FIELD_COUNTRY_MESSAGE"
            query="SELECT country_3_code as value, country_name as country FROM #__mycomponent_country 
            ORDER by country"
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

For birthday use:

```
<field 
  name="birthday" 
  type="calendar" 
  label="Birth Day"
  description="My Desc." 
/>
```

And for country use the SQL as mentioned by @Gord Fisch